# Using Flask button to download list of lists to CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, flask

I am building a really simple web interface with `Flask`. There is one button on the page that should download a `CSV` file when clicked. The source of the CSV is a list of list. Nothing seems to happen when I click the button.

```
from flask import Flask
import csv
import StringIO
from flask import make_response
app = Flask(__name__)
from requests import request

@app.route('/')
def landing():
    return '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Data">'


def data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit'] == 'Get Data':
            csvlist = [['item 1', 'item2'], ['box1', 'box2']]

            si = StringIO.StringIO()
            cw = csv.writer(si)
            cw.writerows(csvlist)
            output = make_response(si.getvalue())
            output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
            output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
            return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues within your code, some being why your button does not do anything.

> 1. You are not creating a form for your button to submit to
> 2. Your `data` function does not have a `route`, so it will not be accessible through form posts
> 3. You need to use `flask request` to access the `method` and `form` data

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
import csv
import StringIO

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def landing():
    return """<form action="data" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Data">
         </form>"""


@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit'] == 'Get Data':
            csvlist = [['item 1', 'item2'], ['box1', 'box2']]

            si = StringIO.StringIO()
            cw = csv.writer(si)
            cw.writerows(csvlist)
            output = make_response(si.getvalue())
            output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
            output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
            return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```